# C# xml documentation error

Tags: c#, documentation

I am trying to add documentation to my C# code. But the following gives me a malformed xml error. I know that the error is because of 'List"Display"'. It's trying to find "/Display". But there won't be a "/Display" because it's a part of my code example. Can someone help me with this? Thank you.

```
    /// <summary>
    ///   Retrieves a list of <c>Display</c>
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    ///   <code>
    ///     List<Display> templates = DisplayManager.GetDisplays();
    ///   </code>
    /// </example>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your code in a [`CDATA`](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) block:

```
///   <code>
///     <![CDATA[
///     List<Display> templates = DisplayManager.GetDisplays();
///     ]]>
///   </code>
```

or encode the angle brackets:

```
///   <code>
///     List&lt;Display&gt; templates = DisplayManager.GetDisplays();
///   </code>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's quite common to write `List{Display}` in XML documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping yout code content within CDATA

```
<![CDATA[List<Display> templates = DisplayManager.GetDisplays();]]>
```

> All text in an XML document will be parsed by the parser.
>
> > But text inside a CDATA section will be ignored by the parser.